# React Native Card Card left border red

Tags: react-native

I am having some difficulty styling an react native elements card and I was wondering if anyone could tell me the best approach to do the styling of the left border of the card. I tried using borderLeftColor but I doesnt work.Only borderTopColor and borderBottomColor work.  Thanks

```
const DeviceInputItems = (props) => {
  return (
    <Card
      containerStyle={{
        padding: 0,
        margin: 5,
        borderLeftColor: "red",
        borderWidth: 4,
      }}
      key={props.key}
    >
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text style={styles.centerText}>
            Hello
          </Text>
      </View>
    </Card>


onst styles = StyleSheet.create({
  centerText: {
    textAlign: "left",
  },
  container: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    flex: 1,
  },
```

Comment: Please, share code in work format (fix brackets, `const` word)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's React Native issue

[borderColor (top left bottom right) styling ignored on Android #19981](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19981)

Comment: I wrote a higher order component with a view and then i was able to style it using borderLeftColor. Too be honest I dont know why it work this way.